# Decimal representation of binary numbers in 2's complement representation

Tags: computer-science, binary

What decimal integer would be stored in 8 bit memory as 110100010 in 2's complement representation?

Comment: If you look up 2's complement, it should not be hard to figure this out.  Try to figure a few simple examples first e.g. all the cases where just one bit is 1.  What is 00000001?  What is 10000000?

Comment: Thanks for the response! how would I handle the 9th digit if the memory is 8bits? I heard of overflow(not sure if its the correct application here), how would I adjust for that?

Comment: What 9th digit?

Comment: Oh, I see that your example has 9 bits (I did not count before).  I don't know.  I would go back to whoever asked the question.  Or go to a computer site.  This is not really a mathematics question.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help

Comment: The *9*-bit decimal number in your question has a decimal value of 418. As far as I know, no computer today operates on 9-bit bytes. However, if there was such a computer, you could just subtract 2 to the 9th power and find that 9-bit unsigned 418 has the same representation as 9-bit signed $418 - 512 = -94$.